# Concatenate List of objects without duplicates

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a list of clients stored in a database. I need to implement the functionality of updating this list, with a check for duplicates. Checking for customer equality is done by comparing email and phone number. So the task boils down to merging the two lists, adding only those customers whose email address and phone number are not in the database.

My question is: Is there a simpler way of doing this?

```
public class DateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestObject t1 = new TestObject(1, "+111", "email1", "Ivan");
        TestObject t2 = new TestObject(2, "+222", "email2", "Ilya");
        TestObject t3 = new TestObject(3, "+333", "email3", "Pavel");
        TestObject t4 = new TestObject(null, "+444", "email4", "Anna");
        TestObject t5 = new TestObject(null, "+111", "email1", "Ivan");
        TestObject t6 = new TestObject(null, "+222", "email2", "Ivan");
        List<TestObject> testObjects = Arrays.asList(t1, t2, t3);
        List<TestObject> newTestObjects = Arrays.asList(t4, t5, t6);
        List<TestObject> notPresentObj = newTestObjects.stream().filter(client -> !testObjects.contains(client)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<TestObject> newList  = Stream.concat(testObjects.stream(),notPresentObj.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(newList);
    }

}

class TestObject {
    private Integer id;
    private String phoneNubmer;
    private String email;
    private String name;


    public TestObject(Integer id, String phoneNubmer, String email, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.phoneNubmer = phoneNubmer;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
    }

  //getters, setters and toString

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TestObject that = (TestObject) o;
        return Objects.equals(phoneNubmer, that.phoneNubmer) && Objects.equals(email, that.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(phoneNubmer, email);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried `distinct` on concatenated stream?

Comment: If the whole list of clients fits in memory - as in your code - then you can implement it much simpler using a HashSet. Adding new clients to it will do the trick. Only objects not yet contained will be added. This is how a set works.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Is there a simpler way of doing this?

If you use a set for the `newTestObjects` data structure, it can be simpler.

```
List<TestObject> testObjects = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(new TestObject(1, "+111", "email1", "Ivan"),
                new TestObject(2, "+222", "email2", "Ilya"),
                new TestObject(3, "+333", "email3", "Pavel")));
Set<TestObject> newTestObjects = new HashSet<>(
        List.of(new TestObject(null, "+444", "email4", "Anna"),
                new TestObject(null, "+111", "email1", "Ivan"),
                new TestObject(null, "+222", "email2", "Ivan")));
```

- first remove the existing objects from the new ones.
- then add back into the original list any that were not removed from the set.

```
newTestObjects.removeAll(testObjects);
testObjects.addAll(newTestObjects);

testObjects.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
TestObject [1, +111, email1, Ivan]
TestObject [2, +222, email2, Ilya]
TestObject [3, +333, email3, Pavel]
TestObject [null, +444, email4, Anna]
```

if you need to preserve the original `testObjects` list, you can do it like this.

```
List<TestObject> newList = new ArrayList<>(testObjects);
newList.addAll(newTestObjects);
```

Using a set for the `newTestObjects` can be significantly faster for large numbers of objects since then objects are hashed, resulting in a faster lookup.